# d3 integration with vue.js components

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vue.js

I am trying to integrate D3 with vue.js.

I am following this simple guide: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/

the guide is asking to append a new div for each new bar.

i have accomplished the integration with a custom directive, in the snippet attached.

i want to use the power of vue.js and instead of appending new `div`, i want to append new components with `props` ...

how is it possible to add new components from a direcive?

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    array: [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
  },
    directives: {
    chart: {
      bind(element, array) {
        d3.select(element)
          .selectAll('div')
          .data(array.value)
          .enter()
          .append('div')
          .style('width', barValue => {
            return barValue * 10 + 'px'
          })
          .text(barValue => {
            return barValue
          })
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.chart div {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background-color: steelblue;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.3.4"></script>
<div id="app">
   <div v-chart="array" class="chart">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue 2, directives are for [DOM manipulation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html).

> Note that in Vue 2.0, the primary form of code reuse and abstraction
> is components - however there may be cases where you just need some
> low-level DOM access on plain elements, and this is where custom
> directives would still be useful.

You shouldn't be adding components from a directive. If you were going to draw a chart using a directive, then what you are doing now is how you might do it.

However, in Vue 2, you really should be doing this in a component.

D3 is unnecessary in this case, given all D3 is doing is adding some `div` elements. This is easily accomplished with a component.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("bar-chart", {
  props: ["chartData", "scale"],
  template: `
    <div>
      <div v-for="item in chartData" :style="{width: item * scale + 'px'}" class="chart">{{item}}</div>
    </div>
  `
})


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    array: [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
  },
})
```

```css
.chart {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background-color: steelblue;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <bar-chart :chart-data="array" scale="10"></bar-chart>
</div>
```

If you're stuck on D3, I still wouldn't likely do this with a directive, but rather with a component.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("bar-chart", {
  props:["chartData"],
  template:`<div class="chart"></div>`,
  mounted(){
    d3.select(this.$el)
          .selectAll('div')
          .data(this.chartData)
          .enter()
          .append('div')
          .style('width', barValue => {
            return barValue * 10 + 'px'
          })
          .text(barValue => {
            return barValue
          })
  }
})


new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: {
    array: [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
  },
})
```

```css
.chart div {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background-color: steelblue;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <bar-chart :chart-data="array"></bar-chart>
</div>
```

Comment: so there is not really a way for making the d3 code, the "append" method, to add vue components instead of DOM nodes?

Comment: @LiranC not really.